# Unable to display Tabview in TabBar, and link the content

Tags: flutter

I need some help implementing the TabView in my code. I've made two separate classes, one with my defaultTabController and TabBar, and one with the TabView. In my Scaffold I am only able to make it display my TabBar, but I am unable to figure out how to link the content to the tabs. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import 'package:anestesi_v1/shared/drawer.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:anestesi_v1/shared/appbar.dart';


class BarneAnestesi extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName ='/BarneAnestesi';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: ApplicationToolbar(),

      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: MyDrawer(),

      body: barnTab(),
      extendBody: barnTabView(),

    );
  }
}
class barnTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,

        child: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.child_care, color: Colors.white,)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.article, color: Colors.white,)),
          ],

        ),),

    );

  }
}

class barnTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
          Text("Test1"),
          Text("Test2"),
        ])

    );
  }
}
```

appbar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ApplicationToolbar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('Ane'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      centerTitle: false,

      actions: <Widget> [
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person, color:Colors.white,),
          label: Text('Logg ut',),
          textColor: Colors.white,


        ),
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color:Colors.white,),
          label: Text("Innstillinger"),
          textColor: Colors.white,

        )
      ],);
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap the `Scaffold` with `DefaultTabController`, so both the `TabBar` and the `TabBarView` are below the `DefaultTabController` in the widget tree

```
import 'package:anestesi_v1/shared/drawer.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:anestesi_v1/shared/appbar.dart';

class BarneAnestesi extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/BarneAnestesi';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: ApplicationToolbar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
        body: barnTabView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class barnTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
      Text("Test1"),
      Text("Test2"),
    ]));
  }
}
```

appbar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ApplicationToolbar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('Ane'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      centerTitle: false,
      // add here the TabBar widget
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(
              icon: Icon(
            Icons.child_care,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
          Tab(
              icon: Icon(
            Icons.article,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget> [
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person, color:Colors.white,),
          label: Text('Logg ut',),
          textColor: Colors.white,


        ),
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color:Colors.white,),
          label: Text("Innstillinger"),
          textColor: Colors.white,

        )
      ],);
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that solution. But I am getting an error on the extendBody-argument. Is that the wrong argument to use?

Comment: I will update my answer in a minute. the TabBarView assigned to the body parameter, and the TabBar needs to be assigned inside the AppBar widget 'bottom' property. this should work for you

Comment: I am using a custom AppBar, the "bottom"-argument gave me errors earlier until I assigned the TabBar to the body-argument.

I'll add my appbar-code in the mainpost

Comment: It wont give you an error because now the 'DefaultTabController' is at the top of the widget tree

Comment: I have already added it to the first post. It is in the bottom of the post.

Comment: and when you add 'barnTab' to the app bar bottom argument it throws you an error?

Comment: I've tried both 

appBar: ApplicationToolbar(
          bottom: barnTab(),
        ),

and

child: Scaffold(
        appBar: ApplicationToolbar(),
        bottom: barnTab(),

It throws me an "The named parameter bottom isn't defined"

Comment: Seems like another issue appeared: "The following _TypeError was thrown building ApplicationToolbar(dirty):
type 'barnTab' is not a subtype of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'" But now at least I am able to set barnTab as a bottomWidget of the appbar!

Comment: just add 'with PreferredSizeWidget' to 'barnTab' class widget

Comment: Seems like we're almost at the finishline. Now the barnTab is overlaying the Appbar.How do I set the preferredsizewidget to appbar + barntab?

Comment: Or make the preferredsize dynamic in the appbar.dart.. it seems like the restriction is there, but I only want it to be expanded for the barntab, not constantly

Comment: I have an idea, look at the updated post i a minute

Comment: The following assertion was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(432.0, 816.0), devicePixelRatio: 2.5, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false, disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional)):
No TabController for TabBar.